# Displaying specific elements depending buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I need to display differents elements on a same page using four buttons to filter it. If I click on the first button of NavigationBar component, one specific div must be displayed.

I have a Home page that must displaying the differents elements :

```
class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  showContent() {
    alert('ok');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Header activeLink={['home']}/>
        <p>Some texte here</p>
        <NavigationBar onClick={this.showContent} firstSection="L'entreprise" secondSection="Pourquoi nous choisir ?"/>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

And my NavigationBar component with the four buttons :

```
class NavigationBar extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navigation-bar flex row between">
        <div onClick={() => {this.props.onClick()}}>
          <p>{this.props.firstSection}</p>
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => {this.props.onClick()}}>
          <p>{this.props.secondSection}</p>
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => {this.props.onClick()}}>
          <p>{this.props.thirdSection}</p>
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => {this.props.onClick()}}>
          <p>{this.props.fourthSection}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NavigationBar;
```

With this code, I can display the alert('ok') when I click on the div of my NavigationBar component but I don't know how to identifying what div was clicked. If I know how to do this, I could easily display specific elements. Thank for your help.

Comment: Do you have a set amount of divs? Or are they dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onClick handler will give you an event object. Pass that event object back to `showContent`. You can also add identifying information to the element:

`<div data-key="foo" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e)}>`

Then:

```
showContent(e) {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-key'));
}
```